# Changing incomplete date and time format in R

Tags: r, date, parsing, time, format

I am struggling for hours to find a proper solution to my problem. I have a vector with dates in following format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM :

```
x <- "08/01/2021 15:44"
```

and I need to change it to YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS, I tried multiple solutions, closest is using

```
x <- parse_date_time(x ,orders = 'ymd HMS')
```

however because input data does not contain seconds, entire parsing is changing date format in a wrong way, ie. 08/01/2021 15:44 into 2008/01/20 21:44

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is different.  It should be either `dmy_hms` or `mdy_hms`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hms(x, truncated = 1)
#[1] "2021-01-08 15:44:00 UTC"
```

Or just use `dmy_hm`

```
dmy_hm(x)
#[1] "2021-01-08 15:44:00 UTC"
```

Comment: It did not help properly. Although it creates proper format, for whatever reason all the dates that I have (span from 2017 to 2021) change to 2020 and I am loosing date info

Comment: @MartinWalczyński use the `truncated`  or use `dmy_hm` as you don't have seconds

Comment: however you have helped a lot! It works when I use dmy_hm :)